# Замучался c CoordinatorLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, coordinator-layout

Помогите "встроить" LinearLayout (далее LL) в корень CoordinatorLayout (далее CL).

Как вообще позиционировать вью внутри CL? Чтобы CL мог управлять ими вью же должны быть его "детьми" первого уровня вложенности? Почему АппБар лэйаут и NestedScroll лэйаут позиционируются корректно друг за другом, а когда вытаскиваю LL, он накладывается на них сверху?

Ниже собственно описание проблемы:
Изначально внутри CL располагались AppBarLayout, NestedScrollView и FloatingActionButton (не интересна, в дальнейшем о FAB упоминать не буду).

Внутри NestedScrollView располагалось два LL (один панель статистики, второй - инфа о пользователе). Потребовалось сделать так, чтобы панель статистики оказалась "непрокручиваемой", то есть вынести его наружу NestedScrollView

Теперь структура внутри CL следующая:
 AppBarLayout, LinearLayout, NestedScrollView
однако  LinearLayout отображается "поверх"  AppBarLayout и NestedScrollView.
как встроить его между ними?

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_coordinator_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/color_primary"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="@color/color_primary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/user_photo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/profile_image_size"
                android:background="@drawable/collapsing_photo"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:titleTextColor="@color/white">

            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nested_scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <include layout="@layout/profile_layout"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <include layout="@layout/statistic_panel" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_right_space"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_black_24dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_layout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Панель статистики, которая как раз не встраивается (statistic_panel)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ll_stat_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/grey"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/padding_xxlarge_24"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/padding_xxlarge_24"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_layout"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/panel_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            style="@style/panel_sub_item"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_xxlarge_24" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/panel_sub_item"
            android:text="@string/panel_raiting"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_large_16" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/line_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_large_56"
        android:background="@color/grey_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/panel_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            style="@style/panel_sub_item"
            android:text="25000"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_xxlarge_24" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/panel_sub_item"
            android:text="@string/panel_count_code_strings"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_large_16" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="@dimen/line_height"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_large_56"
        android:background="@color/grey_light" />

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/panel_item"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            style="@style/panel_sub_item"
            android:text="5"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_xxlarge_24" />

        <TextView
            style="@style/panel_sub_item"
            android:text="@string/panel_projects"
            android:textSize="@dimen/font_large_16" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Вдруг пригодится - LL с профилем пользователя (profile_layout)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_call_black_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_big_72"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_phone"
                    style="@style/item_text_input_layout"
                    android:hint="@string/layout_text_mobile_phone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:text="+79027888883" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_in_talk_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/gorizontal_delimeter" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.left"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_email_black_24dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_big_72"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_email"
                    style="@style/item_text_input_layout"
                    android:hint="@string/layout_text_e_mail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:text="my_mail@mail.my" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_send_black_24dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/gorizontal_delimeter" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.left"
            android:src="@drawable/vk_circle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_big_72"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_vk"
                    style="@style/item_text_input_layout"
                    android:hint="@string/layout_text_vk"
                    android:text="vk.com/novoselov_roman" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.right"
            android:src="@drawable/eye" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/gorizontal_delimeter" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.left"
            android:src="@drawable/github_circle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/size_big_72"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_github"
                    style="@style/item_text_input_layout"
                    android:hint="@string/layout_text_repo"
                    android:text="https://github.com/RNOVOSELOV/DevIntensive" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.right"
            android:src="@drawable/eye" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View style="@style/gorizontal_delimeter" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_small_8"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            style="@style/icon.left"
            android:src="@drawable/account_circle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/spacing_normal_16"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/spacing_medium_32"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small_8">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_about"
                    style="@style/item_text_input_layout"
                    android:hint="@string/layout_text_about"
                    android:text="@string/about" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

После выноса LL из NestedScroll добавил ему след параметры:

```
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
app:layout_anchor="@id/appbar_layout"
app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
```

LL верхним краем приклеилась к аппБару, однако NestedScroll оказался под панелькой, как теперь совместить нижнюю сторону панельки и верхнюю у NestedScroll

Вот так сейчас выглядит активити:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так оно выглядит без панельки (чтобы было понятно что панька накладывается на другую вью):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: для того, чтобы выстроить элементы относительно друг друга, используйте `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: Чтобы CoordinatorLayout мог управлять вьюхами, они должны быть его прямыми детьми, а не вложенными.